# Convert AFNetworking swift 2.3 mock to swift 3?

Tags: swift, afnetworking, swift3

We are trying to convert a swift2.3 AFNetworking mock to swift 3. Here is the Swift 2.3 code:

```
class MockAFHTTPRequestOperationManager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager {

    var capturedPOSTURL = ""
    var capturedPOSTParameters: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]

    internal override func post(_ URLString: String!, parameters: AnyObject!, success: ((AFHTTPRequestOperation?, AnyObject?) -> Void)!, failure: ((AFHTTPRequestOperation?, NSError?) -> Void)!) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {
        capturedPOSTURL = URLString
        capturedPOSTParameters = parameters as! Dictionary
        return AFHTTPRequestOperation()
    }
}
```

Here is the swift 3 code we tried, but got a compilation error when we added the override in front of the `func POST`:

```
    func POST(URLString: String, parameters: AnyObject, success: (_ operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, _ responseObject: AnyObject) -> Void, failure: (_ operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, _ error: NSError) -> Void) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation {

        return AFHTTPRequestOperation()

    }
```

It says the method does not override any method from its superclass.

This is the Objective-C method we are trying to override:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                      parameters:(id)parameters
                         success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                         failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

We are using AFNetworking 2.5.1

How do we override the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager POST method above properly with swift3 syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
    override func post(_ URLString: String, parameters: Any, success: ((_ operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, _ responseObject: Any) -> Void)! , failure: ((_ operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, _ error: Error) -> Void)!) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation {

        return AFHTTPRequestOperation()

    }
```